# Passing a hash string in transaction with smart contracts

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I want to pass a hash string in my transaction but using smart contracts.
Normally this can be done using commant 
eth.sendTransaction({from: accounts[0], to: accounts[1], value: integer, data: string).

In the above way I want to pass a hash string in my transaction using smart contract. I want to save the string in blocks too.

Comment: Define your own smart contract and pass a string to it.  eth.sendTransaction is something provided by go etherum, they are more of pre-defined function. If you want to pass a hash string and save it in block,write your own contract and deploy it.